# Using FakeItEasy, how to get the value set on a property on a fake?

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

Using FakeItEasy, I am trying to capture the setting of a property value on a fake object:

**First the interface:**

```cs
interface ISomeInterface
{
    int MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

**Then a fragment of unit test:**

```cs
var myObject = A.Fake<ISomeInterface>();

int saved = 0;
A.CallTo (() => myObject.MyProperty).Invokes (x => saved = ?????);

SomeMethod (myObject);
Assert.That (saved, Is.EqualTo (100));
```

**And having**

```cs
void SomeMethod (ISomeInterface intf)
{
    intf.MyProperty = 100;
}
```

I don't know what to put to replace the ?????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var myObject = A.Fake<ISomeInterface>();

SomeMethod (myObject);
Assert.That (saved.MyProperty, Is.EqualTo(100));
```

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer, I want the fake object to actually return the value 100 so that other classes using this interface would use that value. I concede that my example was not clear enough. ;)

Comment: Well, there are two ways, either A.CallTo (() => myObject.MyProperty).Returns(100); or just myObject.MyProperty = 100;.

Comment: @Patrik Hägne,

Second one where I assign the property directly is working for me. 

The first one 

A.CallTo(() => dbVM.CreateFolderPath).Returns(somePath);

returned me this exception.

The current proxy generator can not intercept the specified method for the following reason:
    - Non virtual methods can not be intercepted.

Comment: @VivekDev, I guess you're not faking an interface but a concrete class. Make sure to make the property virtual in the class you're faking.